# Bash не видит библиотеку

Tags: python, django, bash

я делал сайт на джанго, решил его загрузить на PythonAnywhere, сделал всё по инструкции, сайт успешно загрузился, но выдаёт ошибку: `No module named 'bs4'`, хоть эта библиотека и была в моём файле с зависимостями он её всё равно не установил, я скачал её через терминал, на всякий случай, пересоздал бд, но всё равно этой библиотеки нет(в pip list она есть), в чём проблема?